# Better Photo/Image Support in photo.SE

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images

Currently the only way to insert is to use good html links, for which there icon for.  I am thinking what might help grow this site if there is a way to **maybe have a popup the shows your gallery from an online site. You click the thumbnail and it gets inserted into the post.**  There might be even an extra box to crop it and scale it if you want to get fancy.

Which site, I don't know.  This seems like the community might know which sites allow for something like this and which people usually use.  **Flickr, smugmug, or something like that** would be candidates I have heard of but I am not sure if they allow for this.

This isn't to spawn lots of "How do I make my image better" , but rather to give more context to questions like "There is clipping in high key areas, how might I repair an image that has this issue, for example..."

**If someone get something like this going in in greasemonkey we should be able to get it ported to the actual site.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We now support integrated image uploading via the standard image button:

[image: hosted image UI]

Comment: I just added a new question regarding this feature and how it affects the cc-wiki licensing:
http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/295/do-photos-uploaded-here-have-to-be-cc-wiki-too

Answer (score 4):

How about taking a "one-box" approach, where a user simply includes a Flickr/smugmug/yfrog URL in their post, and we replace it with the image automatically?

Answer (score 2):

This is a great idea! Everyone has their own 14-step way to upload their photos and link to them, but this Stack Exchange would really rock if it had some built-in Javascript-based tools to upload photos without worrying about where they will be stored, or even to link to photos on sites like Flickr and Picasa in some slick, integrated way.

I'm promoting this to a **Stack Exchange Challenge™**. Is anyone here a JavaScript programmer? Can you write a little greasemonkey script for photo.stackexchange.com that provides easy photo uploading and linking? If someone can do this with Greasemonkey, we'll incorporate it into the site proper so that everyone benefits.